# How to remember the status of the Like Button after re-opening in Flutter using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, flutter, dart

I am using php and mysql as backend when i reload the app the color of button becomes default how can i make it to remember the status of the like button

Comment: you need to store like-event on database

Comment: Can you tell me how to create and store like event

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can store `user_id`, `event_id` & `Like/Dislike` in the `Action table`. Then get that specific user likes array from backed and handle your like/Dislike button.